# Kafka Broker Not able to start

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having a 3 node Kafka Cluster. One of the broker is not starting, i am getting below error. I have tried deleting index files but still, same error coming. Please help to understand what is this issue and how can I recover.

`INFO [2018-09-05 11:58:49,585] kafka.log.Log:[Logging$class:info:66] - [pool-4-thread-1] - [Log partition=Topic3-15, dir=/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 11547004 and log end offset 11559178 in 1552 ms
INFO [2018-09-05 11:58:49,589] kafka.log.Log:[Logging$class:info:66] - [pool-4-thread-1] - [Log partition=Topic3-13, dir=/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs] Recovering unflushed segment 12399433
ERROR [2018-09-05 11:58:49,591] kafka.log.LogManager:[Logging$class:error:74] - [main] - There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: inconsistent range
WARN [2018-09-05 11:58:49,591] kafka.log.Log:[Logging$class:warn:70] - [pool-4-thread-1] - [Log partition=Topic3-35, dir=/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs] Found a corrupted index file corresponding to log file /var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs/Topic3-35/00000000000011110038.log due to Corrupt time index found, time index file (/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs/Topic3-35/00000000000011110038.timeindex) has non-zero size but the last timestamp is 0 which is less than the first timestamp 1536129815049}, recovering segment and rebuilding index files...
INFO [2018-09-05 11:58:49,594] kafka.log.ProducerStateManager:[Logging$class:info:66] - [pool-4-thread-1] - [ProducerStateManager partition=Topic3-35] Loading producer state from snapshot file '/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs/Topic3-35/00000000000011110038.snapshot'
ERROR [2018-09-05 11:58:49,599] kafka.server.KafkaServer:[MarkerIgnoringBase:error:159] - [main] - [KafkaServer id=2] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: inconsistent range
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap$SubMap.(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:2620)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.subMap(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.subMap(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:2114)
    at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$12.apply(Log.scala:1561)
    at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$12.apply(Log.scala:1560)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at kafka.log.Log.logSegments(Log.scala:1560)
    at kafka.log.Log.kafka$log$Log$$recoverSegment(Log.scala:358)
    at kafka.log.Log.recoverLog(Log.scala:448)
    at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:421)
    at kafka.log.Log.(Log.scala:216)
    at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:1747)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.kafka$log$LogManager$$loadLog(LogManager.scala:255)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:335)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO [2018-09-05 11:58:49,606] kafka.server.KafkaServer:[Logging$class:info:66] - [main] - [KafkaServer id=2] shutting down`

Comment: Did you delete only one file or all files related to that offset?

Comment: I have deleted all files for corresponding partition

Comment: I assume you deleted them while the brokers was offline? And the other brokers start okay, so the partition replication would be okay?

Comment: yes before deleting I stop all the brokers and after restarting this broker not coming up